# Passing the value from a servlet to another

Tags: java, servlets

I am trying to pass the value from one servlet to another, and I think I have tried just about everything but it always ends up null. 
I am trying to get the "id" from beside delete task. I have tried storing it in a session, I have tried playing with request.getParameter. Any ideas on what I should do?

```
try{
        int id = DataAccess.getUserID(name);
        list = DataAccess.displayTasks(id);
    }
    catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}

out.println(OurUtils.getHeader("List of Tasks"));
    out.println("<center><h2>List of Your Tasks</h2>");
    out.println("<table>");
    for (Tasks T : list){
        out.println("<tr>");
        out.println("<td><a href = \"DeleteTask?id="+T.getId()+"\">Delete</a></td>");
        out.println("<td><a href = \"ModifyTask?id="+T.getId()+"\">Modify</a></td>");
        out.println("<td>"+T.getTask()+"</td></tr>");
    }
    out.println("</table>");
    out.println("");
    out.println("<a href=\"AddTask\">Add a new task</a>");
    out.println("</center>");
    out.println(OurUtils.getFooter());
```

here is my display task method

```
public static ArrayList<Tasks> displayTasks(int id) throws ClassNotFoundException, 
IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException,SQLException{
Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,sqluser,sqlpass);
st = con.createStatement();
String sql = "SELECT task from Assignment2Tasks where userID = "+id+"";
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);

ArrayList<Tasks> list = new ArrayList<Tasks>();

while(rs.next()){
    Tasks T = new Tasks(rs.getString(1));
    list.add(T);
}

con.close();
return list;
```

Comment: How `list` comes into this code?

Comment: I edited it in my post.

Comment: can't find anything wrong. please provide the other servlets and displayTasks method

Comment: Is `name` coming from client HTTP request? Perhaps, there's no such `name` in your data provider, so `list` is empty? Other option is that  `DataAccess` isn't working properly for some reason.

Comment: Why are you hand-writing HTML print statements instead of using something like Spring MVC or at least JSP?

Comment: I am still learning, this is how I learned how to do it so far.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, maybe you already know it, but this is how your service objects (such as DAO objects) and domain objects (lists of tasks) can be shared across your servlets:

1. In your `web.xml` you define `listener` object, implementing `ServletContextListener`, so listener will be called once application is deployed into Servlet container (jetty, tomcat):

   ```
    <web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
            version="3.1">

       <servlet>
           <servlet-name>Main</servlet-name>
           <servlet-class>vic.web.MainServlet</servlet-class>
           <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
       </servlet>

       <listener>
           <listener-class>vic.web.AppInitializationListener</listener-class>
       </listener>

       <servlet-mapping>
           <servlet-name>Main</servlet-name>
           <url-pattern>/main</url-pattern>
       </servlet-mapping>

   </web-app>
   ```
2. In code of that listener you initialize your data layer and put reference to it inside `ServletContext`, which is guaranteed to be shared across all servlets of your webapp, which are run in the same JVM:

   ```
   public class AppInitializationListener implements ServletContextListener {

       private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MainServlet.class);

       static final String INITIAL_TASKS_KEY = "INITIAL_TASKS_KEY";
       @Override
       public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
           logger.info("Application initialization commences...");
           sce.getServletContext().setAttribute(INITIAL_TASKS_KEY,
                   new TasksList(Arrays.asList("From me to you", "We can work it out", "Long and winding road")
                   ));
       }

       @Override
       public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
       }
   }
   ```
3. In code of your servlet(s), you override `init(ServletConfig config)` method which is called by container once servlet is initialized. There, you reach out for data initialized in listener and here you go!

   ```
   public class MainServlet extends HttpServlet {

       private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MainServlet.class);

       private TasksList initialTasks;

       @Override
       public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
           super.init(config);

           logger.info("Here");

           ServletContext ctx = getServletContext();
           //noinspection unchecked
           initialTasks = (TasksList) ctx.getAttribute(AppInitializationListener.INITIAL_TASKS_KEY);

           logger.info("Got: " + initialTasks);
       }

       @Override
       protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
           PrintWriter writer = resp.getWriter();
           StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("<html><body>Hello there. Here are your tasks:<br><ol><br>\n");
           for (String task : initialTasks.getTasks()) {
               sb.append("<li>").append(task).append("</li><br>\n");
           }
           sb.append("</ol>\n</body></html>");
           writer.write(sb.toString());
           writer.flush();
           writer.close();
       }

   }
   ```
4. Here data layer is just POJO containing static list of tasks. Since you want to get data from DB (naturally), you should put your JDBC initialization code in `listener` as shown above and make listener put obtained `DriverManager` into context.
5. Okay, but in reality you will want to change these things: a) use some MVC framework instead of creating HTML by hand; b) Use `DataSource` and pool of JDBC connections instead of `DriverManager`

Answer (score 1):

I dont know why you're using all those out.println instead of atleast jsp. I've done this in jsp.

My list in servlet

```
List<User> list = userService.viewUser();    //userService is used to access the data from db by calling the daoservice
request.setAttribute("list",list);
rs=request.getRequestDispatcher("manageuser.jsp");
rs.include(request,response);
```

This is my code in jsp, do note that all these data are inside table tag

```
<%List list=(List)request.getAttribute("list");%>   //Getting the list attributes from the appropriate servlet
<c:forEach items="${list}" var="user">      //for each loop
<tr>
    <td><c:out value="${user.userId}" /></td>
    <td><c:out value="${user.userName}" /></td>
    <td><c:out value="${user.emailId}" /></td>
    <td><a href="menuaction?redirectValue=edituser&Id=${user.userId}">Edit</a>
    <a href="menuaction?redirectValue=deleteuser&Id=${user.userId}">Delete</a></td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Then in the servlet where I was doing the deleting operation and editind operation, (for you it's only deletion)

```
int id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("Id")); //Do the appropriate actions from this id variable
```

Comment: I don't know how to use JSP yet.

Comment: @Kalkrin this alternative explains how you can do it, and you should. I don't know which resource you're using to lear about Servlets but seems awful since writing HTML directly from servlet is a bad practice.

Comment: oh!. Now I know why u're using out.println. During my learning phase I didn't do this much stuff in servlet, I moved on to jsp, let me do this in servlet, maybe I'll get the answer tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Inter-servlet communication:
RequestDispatcher object can forward a client's request to a resource(Servelt/Jsp).Here you want Servlet_A to invoke Servlet_B.Use

```
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getRequestDispatcher("Servlet_B");
   dispatcher.forward( request, response );
```

Comment: to pass data between servlet instances, you don't need forwarding

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href = \DeleteTask?id = 15>Delete</a>
```

when user clicks Delete, you can get id by request.getParameter("id")
So you can pass id to other servlet with request.

Also you can store it in session and get it.

```
request.getSession(true).setAttribute("name",'AAAA');

request.getSession().getAttribute("name");
```

Comment: String id;
  id = request.getParameter("id");
     if(id == null) id = "-1";
  try{
   DataAccess.deleteTask(Integer.parseInt(id));
  }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
  response.sendRedirect("DisplayTasks");

Comment: Nice but can you inspect the from browser that the id has value.
Press F12 and search for a element.
Also what is the servlet mapping for \DeleteTask path

Comment: I don't get my get parameter is not working, it worked in a simlular program I did..

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered the solution to my problem. In my DisplayTasks method, I was just pulling the string for the task and putting it in the t object and I was not pulling the ID from the table. I couldn't pass the ID to the other servlet because it was and empty variable..